# filtering adult sites

Tags: java

I have a list of websites from which I need to filter out adult / malware sites. Is there any api which allows this? 
I came across the Yahoo BOSS api .. are there any other api's for this??
Is there any site which maintains a list of such malware/adult links which I can validate against??

Answer (score 0):

Everything that I know of are paid services. None of them That I know or searched offer free lists of adult content sites. Option (A) contact one of the paid services and see if you can get in on there lists. Option (B) Start your own list. Sorry I couldn't help more.